# Speed up an Excel Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I have a macro `PopulateYearlyValues` But it seems to me it's taking way too long

```
Sub PopulateYearlyValues(ByVal Month As Range)
    Dim c As Double
    Dim s As Double
    c = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(UCase(Month.Value), ActiveSheet.Range("AA5:AX5"), 0)
    s = (ActiveSheet.Range("AA5").Column - 1)
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        For i = 7 To 44
            .Range("G" & i).Value = 0
            .Range("H" & i).Value = 0
            For j = 1 To c
                .Range("G" & i).Value = (.Range("G" & i).Value + .Cells(i, s).Offset(0, j))
                .Range("H" & i).Value = (.Range("H" & i).Value + .Cells(i, s).Offset(0, (j + 1)))
                j = j + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I have a range `G7:H44` that needs to be populated with the `SUM` of range `AA7:AX44` but.. it's only every other column:

```
If Month.Value = "January"
    G7  = SUM(AA7)
    H7  = SUM(AB7)
    ...
    G44 = SUM(AA44)
    H44 = SUM(AB44)
End If

If Month.Value = "April"
    G7  = SUM(AA7, AC7, AE7, AG7)
    H7  = SUM(AB7, AD7, AF7, AH7)
    ...
    G44 = SUM(AA44, AC44, AE44, AG44)
    H44 = SUM(AB44, AD44, AF44, AH44)
End If
```

But the macro I have is taking way too long.. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you turned off Application.ScreenUpdate for this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the usual vba optimization methods of setting calculation to manual and disabling ScreenUpdating .

```
Dim calc As XlCalculation
calc = Application.Calculation
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = calc
```

Put your code or function call between `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

[This is from my previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848950/most-efficent-way-to-add-formatting-excel-vba/1849616#1849616)

Comment: Thank you so much. That link also helped me by removing another loop in a different sub. Didn't know you could do .Range(.Cells(7, 2), .Cells(44, 3)).Value = .Range(.Cells(7, m), .Cells(44, (m + 1)).Value

I'm a PHP developer and was asked to make a few macros in Excel. Never done this before.

Comment: Another speed-up is to use arrays instead of ranges whenever possible, especially if the values within those formulas isn't changing over the course of your macro. Set the array to equal the range, loop through the array, then set the range equal to the array.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up, you can also set Application.EnableEvents to false (and subsequently return it to true) to potentially save time depending on what your procedure does.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if this is something I changed when I updated my `PopulateYearlyValues` or what but now I'm running into another problem..

`G7 = Actual | H7 = Plan | I7 = (G7 - H7) | J7 =IF(OR(G7 = 0, I7 = 0), 0, I7 / G7)`

Since I changed the above sub, `I7` and `J7` stay the same when the month selection is changed.. `G7` and `H7` are updating properly though.

I found a fix to it, but it seems there should be a better way..

```
For i = 7 To 44
    For j = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(UCase(Target.Value), .Range("AA5:AX5"), 0)
        .Range("I" & i).Value = "=G" & i & "-H" & i &")"
        .Range("J" & i).Value = "=IF(OR(G" & i & "=0, H" & i & "=0), 0, I" & i & " / G" & i & ")"
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a formula:
SUMIF will sum base on a criteria

```
SUMIF($AA$99:$AX$99;"=1";$AA7:$AX7) ' for G column
SUMIF($AA$99:$AX$99;"=2";$AA7:$AX7) ' for H column
```

The cells in Row 99 (can be **hidden**) have the condition based on  **Month.Value** and the column, yielding "0"(don`t sum yet), "1"(sum to G column) or "2" (sum to H column):

```
=IF(Month.Value>=ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN(AA3)-25)/2;0);2-MOD(COLUMN(AA3);2);0)
```

Regards

Alen