# How to profile/debug VBA script that works fine on XLS files, but hangs on XLSX files?

Tags: performance, excel, debugging, vba

I have a VB script that does row processing on a small Excel file (35 columns, 2000 rows, no hidden content). It takes about 3 seconds to process the file when applied to an .xls file. If I save the .xls as a .xlsx file, the same script takes about 30 to 60 seconds, completely freezing Excel several times in the process (although it finishes and the results are correct).

I suspect some loop parts of the code are responsible, but I need to find out which. I have found scripts like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506143/5064264 which basically amount to timing all parts of the script by hand - similar to `printf`-debugging, which is not very elegant and also consumes much time for large scripts.

**Is there a better alternative to semi-manual profiling, like performance analyzers in most IDEs, or exist any other approaches to this problem?** I do not want to post the code as it is rather long and I also want to solve it for other scripts in the future.

Comment: An xls file has a maximum of 65,536 rows.  An xlsx file has a maximum of 1,048,576 rows.  I'd start by searching for `.Rows`.  My guess is that you have some code iterates the entire worksheet instead of only rows with data in them.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for the suggestion. I did replace those occurrences with fixed values and it seems this may contribute to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in my case was as Comintern's comment suggested - a method was copying whole columns into a dictionary to reorder them, instead of just the cells with values in them. To preserve this for future readers, I am copying his/her excellent comment here, thanks again!

> An xls file has a maximum of 65,536 rows. An xlsx file has a maximum of 1,048,576 rows. I'd start by searching for .Rows. My guess is that you have some code iterates the entire worksheet instead of only rows with data in them.

---

As for generic profiling or how to get there, I used a large amount of *breakpoints* in the editor (set/remove with left-click in the line number column of the code editor):

- I first set them every 20 lines apart in the main method, ran the program with the large dataset, then after each press of continue (F5) manually measured if it was slow or not.
- Then I removed the breakpoints in the fast regions and added additional ones in the slow regions to further narrow it down into methods and then into lines inside the methods.
- At the end, I could verify if by commenting out the responsible line of code and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

yes  - kind of. I use this to test how fast things are running and experiment with different approaches to get better timings. I stole this from somewhere here on SO.

```
 sub thetimingstuff()

 Dim StartTime As Double
 Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

 StartTime = Timer

 'your code goes here

 SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
 MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

 end sub
```

Another EDIT

you could bury debug.print lines sporadically through your code to see how much each chunk takes to execute.